# all possible binary matrices with fixed number of 1

Tags: matlab, matrix

Hi can I generate all possible binary matrices with fixed number of 1's in each matrix of given order in matlab.

For example, all 4x4 matrices with two 1's in each matrix,
[1 1 0 0;0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0],[1 0 0 0;0 1 0 0;0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0], [1 0 0 0;0 0 0 0;1 0 0 0;0 0 0 0]

Comment: Do you mean https://in.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/combvec.html ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a vectorized solution:

```
N = 4; % matrix size
M = 2; % number of ones
ind = nchoosek(1:N^2, M); 
result = zeros(N,N,size(ind,1));
result(bsxfun(@plus, ind, (0:size(ind,1)-1).'*N^2)) = 1;
```

Each matrix is a 3rd-dim slice of `result`:

```
>> result
result(:,:,1) =
     1     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
result(:,:,2) =
     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
···
result(:,:,120) =
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     1
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create every combination there should be (16x15)/2 combinations (Matsize*Matsize-1)/2), because you can choose the fist on anywhere, the second one anywhere but where the first is and devied by 2 because 1-2 is the same as 2-1. Be aware that if you want to have 3 '1' for example you would have to have 16x15x14/6 (as 3 facotrial). There is a MATLAB function for getting every combination and then you just have to create every matrix while using the combinations as indices (in a 4x4 matrix you can address Matrix(2,1) as Matrix(5) ).

```
C = combnk(1:16,2); %16 elements and 2 '1'
Matrizes = zeros(length(C),4,4);

for i=1:size(Matrizes,1)
    Matrizes(i,C(i,:))=1;
end
```

There is most certainly a way to get rid of the for loop, but as I dont know how performance critical this is I just went for the easy way.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all subsets of indices with the length of 2, and then replace `1`s in that indices. First find subsets with specidfied length using the [following code](http://matlabtricks.com/post-9/get-all-subsets-having-a-given-length):

```
function subsets = get_subset(N, c)
   indices = dec2bin(1:(2 ^ N - 1)) - '0';   % indices of all subsets
   counter = sum(indices, 2);                % number of elements in subsets
   subsets = indices(find(counter == c), :);  % select appropriate subsets
end
```

Then, get all possible indices and replace `1`s:

```
n = 10; k = 2;
A = zeros(n);
all = cell(1,nchoosek(n,k));
subsets = get_subset(numel(A), k);
len = size(subsets,1);
for i = 1:len
    temp = A;
    temp(find(subsets(i,:) == 1)) = 1;
    all{i} = temp;
end
```

**UPDATE:**
As a matter of efficiency, instead of `get_subset`, you can use `combnk` as a native function in matlab.

```
n = 10; k = 2;
A = zeros(n);
all = cell(1,nchoosek(n,k));
subsets = combnk(numel(A), k);
len = size(subsets,1);
for i = 1:len
    temp = A;
    temp(find(subsets(i,:) == 1)) = 1;
    all{i} = temp;
end
```

Comment: The code is not working. I think subsets = combnk(1:numel(A),k).  Another thing is, all matrices are same